# How to reduce module duplication across chunks in Webpack 5 using SplitChunksPlugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have a very large code base that is being built with Webpack.

In Webpack 3 we used `CommonsChunkPlugin` to explicitly define chunks for common code, which kept duplication low, but had the downside of being overly prescriptive and therefore hard to maintain as code evolves.

In Webpack 5, however, with `SplitChunksPlugin`, we see an incredible amount of duplicated code in the chunks. Like in the order of 40MB of duplicated modules across <200MB of total chunks. I’ve found examples where a 25KB module was duplicated in 15 different chunks.

I’ve tried many variations of config and I also tried porting our CommonsChunkPlugin logic over into SplitChunksPlugin cache groups, but nothing so far has reduced the duplication a lot.

I’m in the process of debugging into SplitChunksPlugin but so far haven’t made much progress.

I know this is a bit of a general question but I was hoping somebody who knows the SplitChunksPlugin internals could give some idea about how the plugin makes choices about module duplication. Conceptually, is it trying to reduce module duplication to zero (within the configured constraints like minSize, etc)? Or are there reasons why it would prefer to duplicate a 25KB module instead of putting it into a common chunk?

Basically, any insights that might help me focus my search a bit more while playing with config parameters and stepping through SplitChunksPlugin in the debugger would be appreciated. I’m a little lost at the moment!

Comment: The output sounds wrong to me, so maybe some setting you are using is affecting the defaults. I think you would get more help if you posted at least your optimization section of your config but probably the entire config would be the best.

Answer (score 3):

After debugging further, I found a way to eliminate 100% of the duplication (although it didn't have the positive effect I was hoping for).

It seems that the settings `maxInitialRequests` and `maxAsyncRequests` are checked, together with `minSize` in order to see if a chunk should be split.  If a chunk belongs to a chunk group where the number of chunks in the group is greater than the max requests settings, it won't consider a split because it doesn't want to add another request.  The max requests options are set to 30 by default.

In my case, I have a very big code base and most of our chunk groups (grouping determined, I believe, by chunks required for a particular entry point) have way more than 30 chunks in them.  I did an experiment with `maxInitialRequests` and `maxAsyncRequests` both set to 50000, and `minSize` set to 1 and that eliminated nearly 100% of the duplicated modules across chunks.  It dropped from ~95MB of duplicated modules down to 126 bytes.

But... this of course resulted in many more chunks.  And loading these extra chunks in the browser, despite there being zero duplicated modules, actually made the total loaded resources *increase* instead of decrease. My guess is that there are modules I don't need for my tested workflow grouped together in chunks with the modules I do need, so loading more chunks means loading more of the modules I don't need.  Still trying to validate that one...

At any rate, my takeaway from this is that the interactions between the many configuration options in SplitChunksPlugin nearly impossible to reason about without understanding the internals of the code.  And I'm honestly not sure that a configuration exists that would let me get to what we had with CommonsChunkPlugin in terms of common code being logically grouped.  The automatic SplitChunksPlugin approach is convenient in simple cases, but doesn't seem to hold up in large (and admittedly messy) code bases.

I would be more than happy to be proven wrong about that, if somebody has a suggestion for a magical configuration...